# C# ASP.NET MVC: Show Page Render Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to add an output to all my ASP.NET MVC pages via the master page which shows the render time of the current page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is tricky, because before you can render the page you have to have all your ViewData added to it.

You can get the total time it took to execute the controller action by writing a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and overriding `OnActionExecuting` to start a timer, and `OnActionExecuted` to get the elapsed time and store it to `ViewData`.  When the ActionResult is executed, it can take that time and render it into your View.

That may be close enough for your needs?  Unfortunately, to get the grand total time of both the Action and the Result being executed, you would need to override `OnActionExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted` in your Controller, but at that point it's too late to add information to the View, as it's already been rendered.  You could [log it to a file however, see this link for an example](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-14-cs.aspx).

---

Okay, here's an example timer action filter.  Add this as a class into your project, and then you can tag any controller method with `[ActionTimer]`, and it will add the elapsed time into a ViewData bucket called "`_ElapsedTime`", which you can print out on your views.

```
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MvcApplication1  {
    public class ActionTimerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public ActionTimerAttribute()
            {
                // Make sure this attribute executes after every other one!
                this.Order = int.MaxValue;
            }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                var controller = filterContext.Controller;
                if (controller != null)
                {
                    var timer = new Stopwatch();
                    controller.ViewData["_ActionTimer"] = timer;
                    timer.Start();
                }
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }

            public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
            {
                var controller = filterContext.Controller;
                if (controller != null)
                {
                    var timer = (Stopwatch)controller.ViewData["_ActionTimer"];
                    if (timer != null)
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                        controller.ViewData["_ElapsedTime"] = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    }
                }
            }
        } }
```

As I mentioned earlier, this won't include the time it took to actually render the `ActionResult`.  If you take a look at the example I linked though, it shows you how you could do this to a log file, and also gives you an idea of how the four action filter events can be used.

Comment: Could you give me a small example how to do at least the easier way (overriding ActionFilter and then storing the result in ViewData)?

Comment: Sure... give me about 20 minutes here and I'll be able to get back to you and type one up.

Comment: This is great - one question: why do you keep checking for controller being null? Can the OnActionExecuting event fire without a controller?

Comment: Yep.  You can do this:  ActionTimerAttribute att = new ActionTimerAttribute(); att.OnActionExecuted(new ActionExecutedContext());.   Why someone would do that is beyond me, but it's possible.

Comment: Couldn't you stick the StopWatch in the ViewData in OnExecuting and then in the _Layout use Razor to always call Stop and pull that reference out to get the fully elapsed time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **time the Action**, you can create an **IActionFilter**, which has start and stop events **OnActionExecuting**, **OnActionExecuted**.  But that is only the controller time.

To grab the **full time**, you need to also know the **IResultFilter** start and stop times, which has events **OnResultExecuting**, **OnResultExecuted**.

**[This](https://books.google.com/books?id=AqoIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA516&lpg=PA516&dq=OnResultExecuted%20total%20time%20elapsed&source=bl&ots=swjXqauQnN&sig=uMprmd66AKKA-I7ONk-hvAuR0Ys&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIu9Li1eicyQIVSjomCh1ysgaR#v=onepage&q=OnResultExecuted%20total%20time%20elapsed&f=false)** is an **example** that actually **writes to the Response** in **OnResultExecuted**, so it suggests such may still be possible at that time.  It does a **filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write** call in the OnResultExecuted method.

For my personal use, I just want to know who's doing what, what pages are getting hit, and performance wise, what's taking too much time.  I log this to a database, but don't put it on every page.  (I also store the User, if authenticated, which isn't shown below.)

**Particularly, it was for a DevExpress Large Data Grid, which caused me to need to not just time the Action, but start also timing the Result as well.**

```
 public class Log : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = new SomeExampleEntities();
            WebLog webLog = new WebLog();

            webLog.LogDate = DateTime.Now;

            // Whatever you want to log
            webLog.Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            webLog.IPAddress = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
            webLog.SessionId = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID;

            db.WebLogs.Add(webLog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["WebLog"] = webLog;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["WebLog_db"] = db;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    // This is fired when leaving the controller action, before running the View/Result
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
            WebLog webLog = (WebLog)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["WebLog"];
            webLog.ActionElapsed = (decimal)(((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - webLog.LogDate)).TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0000);
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }

    //This is fired after the result is actually executed, not just after the Action returns a View or Result
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            UsisWebEntities db = (UsisWebEntities)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["WebLog_db"];
            WebLog webLog = (WebLog)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["WebLog"];

            webLog.Elapsed = (decimal)(((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - webLog.LogDate)).TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0000);
            webLog.ResultElapsed = webLog.Elapsed - webLog.ActionElapsed;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using JavaScript.

Have two times one at the start of the load of the page and one at then end of the page and then you can do a difference for the total time.

By doing it from client side script you can get the entire time it take the page to load versus how long the server takes.

Comment: this will show you how long it took for the browser (not the server) to render the page

Comment: Using Javascript in this manner would only be able to tell him the time it took for the browser to render the page between the Javascript calls. This has nothing to do with the time it takes for the server to serve the request.

Comment: Depends on your point of view...if you are doing this for the benefit of the user experience, it's completely valid.  You are doing it for the purpose of server performance tuning it's not.  But the OP is unclear on the purpose.

Comment: No where in the question does it state that the user only cares about server time.

Comment: @dionysus: Yes, I meant server time. Thank you though!
@webjedi: Yes this is just to have a simple way to keep track of performance.